# python : why it is not printing

Tags: python, loops

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i=0
score=PlayListRatings[0]
while (i < len(PlayListRatings) and score<6):
    score=PlayListRatings[i]
    print(score)
    i=i+1
```

Write a while loop to display the values of the Rating of an album playlist stored in the list PlayListRatings. If the score is less than 6, exit the loop. The list PlayListRatings is given by:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
```

Not printing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
score<6
```

is `False`, so the `while` loop never starts.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your code will fail on the first iteration since it is not smaller than 6.

Instead, you should change the `score < 6` to `score >= 6` and using `PlayListRatings[i]` instead of `score`.

Changing the score condition would fit the statement of:

> If the score is less than 6, exit the loop.

In addition, we have to use `PlayListRatings[i]` instead of `score` because `score` would end up lagging behind by one element. This is because `score` is only updated in the while loop.
You could also fix this by changing `score=PlayListRatings[i]` to `score=PlayListRatings[i + 1]` and placing it underneath `print(score)`.

With these changes, your code would look like this:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0
while (i < len(PlayListRatings) and PlayListRatings[i] >= 6):
    print(PlayListRatings[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: `score` is updated after the test and before printing.

Comment: @tobias_k Updated the answer to not print the first score under 6, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1):

You got the condition in your loop backwards: You want the loop to *stop* once `score < 6`, not continue `while` that condition holds! You can change that bit to `>= 6`, but you'll have to change the body of the loop, too, or it will still print the first score that's `< 6`. Here are some options, all doing without an index variable:

- using `break`:

  ```
  for score in PlaylistRating:
      if score < 6:
          break
      print(score)
  ```
- using `itertools.takewhile`:

  ```
  for score in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x >= 6, PlayListRatings):
      print(score)
  ```
- using `iter`, `next` (with default), and `:=` (3.8 and later)

  ```
  it = iter(PlayListRatings)
  while (score := next(it, -1)) >= 6:
      print(score)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

score = 10 is not < 6, that means zero iterations for you while loop.